# Zend: Unable to access form in controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms

First I created a project using **Zend_Tool**. Then created a controller **AuthenticationController** in default module.

Created Form in **projectfolder/application/forms/Login.php**

```
class Forms_Login extends Zend_Form {
    public function _construct() {
        // add elements
    }
}
```

Accessing Form in **myproject/application/controllers/AuthenticationController.php**

```
public function loginAction() {
   $this->view->form = new Form_Login();
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Application_Forms_Login' not found in /var/www/student/application/controllers/AuthenticationController.php on line 19
```

How can I access it with same form class name without including this file in AuthenticationController??

May be I have to tell zend in Bootstrap.php about this but I wan unable to find a sample code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should declare them in your `bootstrap.php` file like so:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoLoader=Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $resourceLoader=new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
            'basePath'=>APPLICATION_PATH,
            'namespace'=>'',
            'resourceTypes'=>array(
                'form'=>array(
                    'path'=>'forms/',
                    'namespace'=>'Forms_'
                )                
            )

            ));


        $autoLoader->pushAutoloader($resourceLoader);




    }


}
```

Comment: IIRC autoloads prefix with default too, so if u dont want to mess with the autoloader, you could just name your form Default_Form_Login